# Maven clean package main class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an Eclipse Java project and the following Maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Initial stuff not include for simplicity -->

    <!-- Repositories -->
    <repositories>
    </repositories>  
  
    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    
    
    <!-- Build  -->  
    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.ParserEngine</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Resources managing plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <!-- here the phase you need -->
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                              <resources>          
                                <resource>
                                  <directory>models/</directory>
                                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                              </resources>              
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
              </plugin>

            
            <!-- Clean plugin  -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                      <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                  <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                  <includes>
                                    <include>output.txt</include>
                                  </includes>
                              <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                      </filesets>
                </configuration>
          </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

When I run

```
mvn clean package
```

I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.ParserEngine
```

I also tried the shade plugin, but without any luck.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>main.ParserEngine</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I managed to get it working only after cleaning the project in Eclipse through Project > Clean > Clean selected projects.

This is weird. Any ideas what is happening?

---

### Update

I created a simple Eclipse project (including some library dependencies) and used the same Maven pom.xml. I then ran:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/MyProject.jar
```

and the jar executes perfectly fine.

Any thoughts about this behaviour or what might be wrong?

---

### Update 2: Bug found

Apparently, the Eclipse project didn't follow [Maven conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and pom.xml didn't make the necessary changes to these conventions, e.g.,  the following was missing

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

Lesson learnt: If you don't follow Maven conventions, make sure to configure your pom.xml properly. Closing the thread.

Comment: *I managed to get it working only after cleaning the project in Eclipse through Project > Clean > Clean selected projects.*.. could probably because of an older cached jar which couldn't provide the `ParserEngine` class.

Comment: It could be, but since I want to distribute the project to others, I'd like them to be able to create the jar automatically. There should be a way to do it through maven, I think.

Comment: `mvn clean package` should do it for all. Its just that your cache seems to be corrupted.

Comment: Any idea how can I check if this is the case and fix the problem?

Comment: @nullpointer, this issue also happens on my local machine. If I don't clean the problem using eclipse, and I use only mvn clean package, the problem is still there. Is there a chance it's something wrong with pom.xml?

Comment: @STiGMa Make sure your main class isn't extending any 3rd party classes.

Comment: @PratikAmbani, thanks. It doesn't however.

Comment: @STiGMa Well I get a Build Success for the same configuration as yours. Just make sure your classpath for the `ParserEngine` class is correct. Would also suggest to create a package and specify the path. e.g `com.ParserEngine` where com would be the package created under java directory of your project.

Comment: @nullpointer, thanks for trying it out. I also get build success, but when I run  the fat jar, I get the exception I mentioned. Have you tried to run it and everything works fine?

Comment: try using maven jar plugin